# Javascript Request library avoid deep nesting

Tags: javascript, request

Code below works, but how can I avoid this nesting of the requests?

Goal is to open the page `urlBriefArea` that requires a cookie set in, plus authentication.

First GET request is to get the cookie value, second is a POST to login, third is the page I want.

I've tried to pass cookieJar in all requests in sequence but it does not seem to have an effect.

```
var request = require('request');

var cookieJar = request.jar();
var request = request.defaults({jar: true})

var loginUrl = 'http://www.nats-uk.ead-it.com/fwf-natsuk/public/user/account/login.faces';

request.get({url: loginUrl, jar: cookieJar}, function() {

    var postParameters = {
        'j_username': process.env.NATS_USERNAME,
        'j_password': process.env.NATS_PASSWORD,
        'mainForm:login': 'Login',
        'mainForm_SUBMIT': '1',
        'mainForm:_idcl': '',
        'mainForm:_link_hidden_': '',
        'javax.faces.ViewState': 'rO0ABXVyABNbTGphdmEubGFuZy5PYmplY3Q7kM5YnxBzKWwCAAB4cAAAAAN0AAExcHQAHy9wdWJsaWMvdXNlci9hY2NvdW50L2xvZ2luLmpzcHg='
    }

    request.post({url: loginUrl, jar: cookieJar, formData: postParameters, followRedirect: false}, 
        function optionalCallback(error, response, body) {  
            var cookie_string = cookieJar.getCookieString(loginUrl); 
            var cookies = cookieJar.getCookies(loginUrl);

            console.log(response.request.headers);
            console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
            console.log('body:', body);

            var urlBriefArea = 'http://www.nats-uk.ead-it.com/fwf-natsuk/restricted/user/ino/brief_aerodrome.faces';
            request({url: urlBriefArea, jar: cookieJar}, function (error, response, body) {

            console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
            console.log('body:', body);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Use Promises instead of callbacks. You may also define functions on the top level instead of inside parameter lists.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thank you for your suggestions. I've learned about Promises and refactored to the code in answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Attempt using Promises and functions in the top level.

```
const rp = require('request-promise-native');

var cookieJar = rp.jar();

var loginUrl = 'http://www.nats-uk.ead-it.com/fwf-natsuk/public/user/account/login.faces';

var postParameters = {
    'j_username': process.env.NATS_USERNAME,
    'j_password': process.env.NATS_PASSWORD,
    'mainForm:login': 'Login',
    'mainForm_SUBMIT': '1',
    'mainForm:_idcl': '',
    'mainForm:_link_hidden_': '',
    'javax.faces.ViewState': 'rO0ABXVyABNbTGphdmEubGFuZy5PYmplY3Q7kM5YnxBzKWwCAAB4cAAAAAN0AAExcHQAHy9wdWJsaWMvdXNlci9hY2NvdW50L2xvZ2luLmpzcHg='
}

function openLogin()
{
    return rp.get({url: loginUrl, jar: cookieJar});
}

function login() {
    return rp.post({url: loginUrl, jar: cookieJar, formData: postParameters,
            followRedirect: false, simple: false}, 
            handlePostLogin)
}

function handlePostLogin(error, response, body) {  
    var cookie_string = cookieJar.getCookieString(loginUrl); 
    var cookies = cookieJar.getCookies(loginUrl);

    console.log(response.request.headers['cookie']);
    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
}

function getAerodrome(result) {
    var urlBriefArea = 'http://www.nats-uk.ead-it.com/fwf-natsuk/restricted/user/ino/brief_aerodrome.faces';
    return rp.get({url: urlBriefArea, jar: cookieJar, resolveWithFullResponse: true});
}

function handleUrlBriefArea(response)
{
    console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
    console.log(response.body.includes('Ricardo'));
}

openLogin()
    .then(login)
    .then(getAerodrome)
    .then(handleUrlBriefArea);
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance updated code to return Promises from functions and chain the calls at the end. Moved functions to top level.

Comment: Yep, that looks a whole lot better! Nice! :)